# How can I double every character in a file excepting newlines?

Tags: bash, files, text

Ηow can I double every character in a file except newlines? Ιt should look something like this:

File content before:

```
echo hello world
```

File content after:

```
eecchhoo  hheelllloo  wwoorrlldd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/./&&/g' yourfile
```

Ex.

```
$ echo 'echo hello world' | sed 's/./&&/g'
eecchhoo  hheelllloo  wwoorrlldd
```

---

Alternatively, with Perl's string multiplication operator:

```
$ echo 'echo hello world' | perl -lne 'print map { $_ x 2 } split //'
eecchhoo  hheelllloo  wwoorrlldd
```

It's possible to do string concatenation in awk of course, but AFAIK not without an explicit loop over characters:

```
$ echo 'echo hello world' | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=""} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i = $i $i}1'
eecchhoo  hheelllloo  wwoorrlldd
```

Comment: Where sed uses newline as line separator not subject to substitution and & references the matched regexp, a single character in this case. The /g reads "g" like "global" so substitution does not stop after the first match.

Comment: @steeldriver Well, of course you can do `awk '{gsub(/./,"&&"); print}'`.

Comment: @Scott true - I was thinking of string concatenation a la perl specifically, i.e. that there's no awk equivalent of the perl `map` function